# Markdown に含まれるコードをシンタックスハイライトするには？

Tags: markdown

Markdown で書いた文書にシンタックスハイライトした形でソースコードを掲載したいと考えています。Pygments 等のツールを使って Markdown 中のコードをハイライトするにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

コマンドラインで動作する Markdown→HTML 変換ツールでシンタックスハイライトができるようなツールがあれば教えていただきたいです。またできれば GitHub-flavored Markdown が扱えればなお嬉しいです。

よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Grip - Github Readme Instant Preview](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip) を使ってみるのはどうでしょうか．

以下のコマンドを実行してインストールし，

```
% pip install grip
```

以下のコマンドを実行すると Github-flavored Markdown なファイル (`file.md`) が HTML (`file.html`) に変換されます．文章中のソースコードは Pygments によってシンタックスハイライトされます．

```
% grip --export --gfm file.md
```

**補足:**

- `--export` オプションを指定しない場合は，`localhost:5000` を Web ブラウザで開くことで変換後の内容を閲覧できます．
- Grip 3.0.0 と Python 3.4.0 の組み合わせでは `--export` オプションによる .md -> .html 変換が正常に実行できませんでした．Python 2.7 では正常に動作しました．

Answer (score 1):

[Python-markdown](http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/)と[Pygments](http://pygments.org/)の組み合わせであれば、こんな感じでしょうか。

```
$ python -m markdown -x cod hoge.md > hoge.html
$ pygmentize -S default -f html > code.css
```

あとは`hoge.html`に`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./code.css" type="text/css" media="all" />`を入れれば、カラーで表示されるようになると思います。

まあPygmentsに拘らなければGripか[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)の方がラクな気がしますが…。